# Upgrading from tomcat6 to tomcat7 giving errors AbstractMethod Error

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, tomcat6, abstract-methods

I have upgrade the tomcat version from tomcat6 to tomcat7 for my web application. On click of a button, AbstractMethod Error is thrown on the page.

Here is the snapshot :

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:916)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:845)
    com.web.console.jsp.editCDTemplate_jsp._jspService(editCDTemplate_jsp.java:203)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1056)
    org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(TilesRequestProcessor.java:261)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(RequestProcessor.java:388)
    org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(TilesRequestProcessor.java:316)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:231)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1164)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:397)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    com.web.console.CharsetFilter.doFilter(CharsetFilter.java:16)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)


root cause 

java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.isAsyncStarted(ServletRequestWrapper.java:396)
    com.web.console.jsp.editCDTemplate_jsp._jspService(editCDTemplate_jsp.java:166)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1056)
    org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(TilesRequestProcessor.java:261)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(RequestProcessor.java:388)
    org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(TilesRequestProcessor.java:316)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:231)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1164)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:397)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    com.web.console.CharsetFilter.doFilter(CharsetFilter.java:16)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

The above error occurs on click of button. Only one single button is producing this error.

**EDIT**
On Pressing the button the following jsp should be displayed but it is throwing the above exception.
**CODE SNIPPET**

```
<console:page url="emptyPage.jsp"
       title="com.web.template">
  <console:menu>
  </console:menu>
  <console:header>
        <%if ( request.getParameter("mode").equals("edit") ) {%>
                <bean:message key="com.web.editTemplate"/>
    <%} else { %>
        <bean:message key="com.web.create"/>
    <%}%>
  </console:header>
  <console:pageBody>
        <tr><td><table width="100%"><tr><td>
         <%

      ServletContext pwgContext = getServletContext().getContext("/pwg");
      ivr_005fcallflow_005fframe_jsp.storeAdminSessionIdInContext(pwgContext, session.getId());
        WebConsoleSession webConsoleSession = (WebConsoleSession)session.getAttribute(LoginAction.WEB_CONSOLE_SESSION_KEY);
        if ( webConsoleSession != null )
              ivr_005fcallflow_005fframe_jsp.storeFPSAAdminSessionIdInContext( pwgContext, webConsoleSession.getSessionId() );
      RequestDispatcher dispatcher = pwgContext.getRequestDispatcher("/callflow");

      InvokeServletTag.FakeRequest subRequest = new InvokeServletTag.FakeRequest(request);
      if (request.getParameter("template") != null) {
          subRequest.setParameter("callFlowNumber", request.getParameter("template"));
      }
      InvokeServletTag.FakeResponse subResponse = new InvokeServletTag.FakeResponse();
      dispatcher.include(subRequest, subResponse);
      subResponse.flushTo(out);

          %>
        </td></tr></table></td></tr>
    <html:errors/>
  </console:pageBody>
</console:page>
```

Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: check ur build path and remove error causing jars

Comment: Could you also post your relevant code, please?

Comment: @Bono Added some code snippet

Comment: Any update on this. did anyone find something wrong in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `servlet-api, servlet, jsp-api and jasper` jars from your build path, You ll see some compilation problems but it ll be taken care by the container. Alternatively you can edit them and point to the new jar files

Comment: which jars are you talking about ? jars from previous tomcat version to remove and add the new one from tomcat7 jar files.

Comment: Simply remove from the build path and deploy your web app to tomcat7, These jars will  be there in tomcat 7

Comment: i have following jars available in tomcat folder.
ant.jar, commons-dbcp-1.2.1.jar, jasper-compiler.jar, naming-common.jar, naming-resources.jar, servlet-api.jar, jsp-api.jar, naming-java.jar but didn't find servlet.jar and jasper.jar file. What are library differences between tomcat6 and tomcat7. Could u please give me some link for that.

Comment: Got the solution for this. I uploaded tomcat7 libs at build machine and implemented all the abstract methods in desired class. Thanks for the responses.